# How to create multiple targets in Makefile based on integer suffix

Tags: makefile

I have a file "data" and some script "command".

I want to create a Makefile containing multiple target rules which together achieve this:

```
for i in 1 to 100:
    // i-th rule depends on data, command, part$(i)/output1 and part$(i)/output2
    mkir part$(i)
    command data $(i) part$(i)/output1 part$(i)/output2
```

I dont want to write them by hand.

Comment: Your comment "i-th rule depends on data, command, part$(i)/output1 and part$(i)/output2" can't be right.  How can a rule that make the directory `part$(i)` _depend on_ the files `part$(i)/output1` and `part$(i)/output2`?

Comment: Ok so assume these directories are already there

Comment: It's not the directories that's the problem.  If you are really saying that the target depends on the output1 and output2 files; that they're input to `command`, then what is the _result_ of running the rules?  What files are generated when the rule is invoked?  Every makefile rule has three parts: the inputs (prerequisites), the outputs (targets), and the commands to transform them (recipe).  Your question is not clearly stating what those are in your situation.

Comment: Oh sorry it was a mistake, it should depend only on data and command

Comment: So, does that mean that output1 and output2 are the files that are generated (the targets)?  That's the information missing from your question.  Anyway, looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment above, your question doesn't provide the correct information.  However here's a cut at it, maybe it's close enough that you can modify it:

```
NUM := $(shell seq 1 100)
TARGETS := $(foreach I,$(NUM),part$I/output1 part$I/output2)

all: $(TARGETS)

part%/output1 part%/output2 : command data
        mkdir part$*
        command data $* part$*/output1 part$*/output2
```